# Extracting field from map in an array of maps

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need a firestore rule that allows access for user ids that are in the users field in a document:

```
Document 1:
    uid: 13423425,
    ...,
    users: [{uid: 123, email: john@gmail.com}, {uid: 456, email: jill@gmail.com}]
```

User `123` should be able to access this field, but a user `999` would not be able to access this document.  How do I write a firestore rule that allows me to check whether a given user id is in the `users` field?  I tried using the `IN` operator but it doesn't work in this case since it is an array of maps (not an array of strings or numbers).  Essentially I'm trying to write a rule like this (using a map):

```
function isAllowed(sometableId) {
    return request.auth.uid != null
    && request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/sometable/$(sometableId)).data.users.map(user => user.uid);
}


match /sometable/{sometableId} {
  allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
  allow read, write: if isAllowed(sometableId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible with your document structure.  Rules currently provide no way to iterate an array or perform a map-like operation.  Consider a different structure instead that puts the values you want to filter as the array values (yes, you will be duplicating data from users into a new field):

```
Document 1:
    uid: 13423425,
    ...,
    users: ...,
    fullAccess: ['123', '456']
```

Now your rule can be written like this:

```
match /sometable/{sometableId} {
  allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.fullAccess;
}
```

You could also solve this using a map with uid values for keys, and nested properties containing a boolean values that indicates read/write access.

Comment: How would your second suggestion work?  Would I do the following: `users: {123: 'john@gmail.com', 456: 'jill@gmail.com'}]` in this case how would the rule look

Comment: You still need a boolean to check in the document data.

Comment: @DougStevenson can you elaborate on the need for the boolean when going the route of a map of uid keys? Could it be enough that if the key `123` is found in the users map, then user `123` is granted access?